# Regex match and convert in Ansible facts

Tags: ansible

I am trying to get the ELB name using Ansible dig, but it is returning DNS name. Is there a way I can match the DNS name pattern and get the ELB name out of DNS. For example, I am trying to get ELB name from below DNS name in Ansible get fact.

`internal-synergy-so-synergyin-883nxyin6e2o-278193237.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com.`

should return:

`synergy-so-synergyin-883NXYIN6E2O`

the current code I am using is:

```
  set_fact:
    input: "{{ elb_name }}"
    target: "{{ input | regex_findall('^[a-zA-Z]+-[a-zA-Z]+-[a-zA-Z]+-[A-Za-z0-9]+')}}"
  tags:
    - always
```

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74339916/edit) and include the code you have that is not working, along with any errors it produces. This is not a consultancy website

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the input

```yaml
input: internal-synergy-so-synergyin-883nxyin6e2o-278193237.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com.
```

Split the items of the target

```yaml
target_arr: "{{ input|split('.')|first|split('-') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
target_arr:
  - internal
  - synergy
  - so
  - synergyin
  - 883nxyin6e2o
  - '278193237'
```

Put together the name of the target

```yaml
target: "{{ (target_arr[1:-2] + [target_arr[-2]|upper])|join('-') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  target: synergy-so-synergyin-883NXYIN6E2O
```

---

Q: ***"No filter named `split`"***

A: Use `.split()` method

```yaml
target_arr: "{{ (input.split('.')|first).split('-') }}"
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    input: internal-synergy-so-synergyin-883nxyin6e2o-278193237.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com.

    target_arr: "{{ input|split('.')|first|split('-') }}"
    target: "{{ (target_arr[1:-2] + [target_arr[-2]|upper])|join('-') }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: target_arr
    - debug:
        var: target
```

Comment: is there any way this could work with ansible 2.9.25. It is throwing the below error complaining on split filter.

{"msg": "template error while templating string: no filter named 'split'

Comment: Use `.split()` method.

Answer (score 1):

```
^[^-]+-\K[^.]+(?=-)
```

That regex should give you what you want. You can check this [Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/jdPJJP/1).

`^` asserts position at start of a line

`[^-]` match a single character not present in the list

`+` matches the previous token between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible

`-` matches the character -

`\K` resets the starting point of the reported match

`[^.]` match a single character not present in the list

`+` matches the previous token between one and unlimited times

`(?=-)` positive lookahead that matches `-`